# How to rename top-level functions via Terser when using webpack with modules?

Tags: webpack, obfuscation, terser

I'm using webpack 4 to bundle a series of TypeScript files with import/export into a single bundle.js. Then I'm trying to use Terser to obfuscate the final output. I get valid output, however, what start out as top-level functions for me in my code is being output by webpack in such a way that Terser refuses to mangle the function names.

Any idea how to get Terser to rename these functions or how to get webpack to output without using the **webpack_require** lines below, which seem to through off Terser by making my functions into methods on an object.

```
function setCommands() {
//My original function here. Looking to have "setCommands" get renamed for obfuscation.
}

//Terser appears not to mangle the above name due to the below code...
//How can I obfuscate with this via Terser or get webpack to not output this?
//Other stuff created by webpack for bundle.js output

/* harmony reexport (safe) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "setCommands", function() { return _panelUI__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16__["setCommands"]; });

/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "setCommands", function() { return setCommands; });
```

Reference:  webpack.config.js file...

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'none',
    entry: './src/js/startHere.ts',
    devtool: 'source-map', 
    output: {
        filename: '../dist/bundled.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    },
    watch: true,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'tslint-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    performance: {
        //suppress yellow errors about file size.
        hints: 'warning', 
        maxEntrypointSize: 3000000,
        maxAssetSize: 3000000, 
    },
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.